# How to fix the ld: warning: ignoring file Atome error?

Tags: c

I'm getting this error when linking:

> ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/martin/Documents/flanday, file was
>   built for unsupported file format ( 0x23 0x69 0x6E 0x63 0x6C 0x75 0x64
>   0x65 0x20 0x3C 0x73 0x74 0x64 0x69 0x6F 0x2E ) which is not the
>   architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/martin/Documents/flanday
>   Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_main", referenced from:
>   implicit entry/start for main executable ld: symbol(s) not found for
>   architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

How can I fix it?

Comment: How to fix that ?

Comment: Don’t list that file as an input to the linker.

Answer (score 2):

> 0x23 0x69 0x6E 0x63 0x6C 0x75 0x64 0x65 0x20 0x3C 0x73 0x74 0x64 0x69 0x6F 0x2E

If you interpret those bytes as ASCII, you get `#include <stdio.`

In other words, you're passing a C source file to your linker, which tries to interpret it as an object file, but fails, obviously.

To solve this, make sure that your source files aren't passed as inputs to `ld`.